# converting c# code to powershell where it needs to consume dllimport

Tags: c#, powershell, static, dllimport, extern

Say I have following c# code but now I need to convert to PowerShell. I got the DllImport piece but the c# code also has the static extern piece to it. Do I need to have same declaration in Powershell. If yes, could you guide me to correct syntax in powershell.

Thanks

```
[DllImport(@"C:\PDFConv\bin\Conv2PDF.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern UInt32 ProcessConv(UInt32 val, string lpSourcePath, String lpSourceFile, string lpDestPath, string lpDestFile);


private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
  ProcessConv(1, "C:\\source", "test.docx", "C:\\dest\\pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Lee Holmes blog post C.B. mentions, look at the help on Add-Type, specifically example #5.

```
man Add-Type -Examples
```